# programmatically select part of content on another contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div  id="leftdiv"   style="float:left;display:inline-block;height:100px;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14px;width:300px;border:1px solid red;" contenteditable>
    <div>
        first text
    </div>
    <div>
        second text
    </div>
    ...
    <div>
        other texts
    </div>
</div>
<div  id="rightdiv" style="margin-left:1em;display:inline-block;float:left;width:300px;height:100px;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14px;border:1px solid red;" contenteditable>
    <div>
        first text
    </div>
    <div>
        second text
    </div>
    ...
    <div>
        other texts
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two contenteditable divs and these divs have exactly the same content. When I highlight part of content  in leftdiv like "ond" in "second" text using mouse, i want exactly the same part in rightdiv highlighted at the same time. Eventually  2 highlighting in seperate divs will occur simultaneously.

I have tried this but nothing happens.

```
  $('#leftdiv').on('mousedown', function() {
        $('#leftdiv').on('selectstart', function() {
            document.getElementById('rightdiv').tabIndex = -1 ;
            document.getElementById('rightdiv').focus();
            var range  = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(this);
            var sel  = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        });
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't have more than one *real* selection in Web browsers. The best you could do is fake it by creating elements to wrap around the content you want to appear to be highlighted (but that's a much more difficult problem to solve).

Answer (score 1):

This is far from a complete solution, and it makes use of css to fake the second selection, but perhaps it will give you an idea.

Try selecting "ond" in the leftdiv, as you suggested in your description, and "ond" is highlighted in the rightdiv (after the selection is complete - it won't live update as you drag the mouse to change the selection).

If you select content across multiple divs within leftdiv, this will break, and if you select text that appears multiple times, it will highlight the first match, not the exact match.  Like I said, just trying to give you a potential path to explore further.

```js
$('#leftdiv').on('mouseup', function() {
    $("*").removeClass("highlight");
    $('#rightdiv').html($('#leftdiv').html());
    var selection = window.getSelection()+"";   
    var matchStart = $('#rightdiv').html().indexOf(selection);
    var matchEnd = matchStart + selection.length - 1;
    var beforeMatch = $('#rightdiv').html().slice(0, matchStart);
    var matchText = $('#rightdiv').html().slice(matchStart, matchEnd + 1);
    var afterMatch = $('#rightdiv').html().slice(matchEnd + 1);
    $('#rightdiv').html(beforeMatch + "<font class='highlight'>" + matchText + "</font>" + afterMatch);
    
});
```

```css
.highlight {background-color:#b4daf7;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="leftdiv"   style="float:left;display:inline-block;height:100px;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14px;width:300px;border:1px solid red;" contenteditable>
    <div>
        first text
    </div>
    <div>
        second text
    </div>
    ...
    <div>
        other texts
    </div>
</div>
<div  id="rightdiv" style="margin-left:1em;display:inline-block;float:left;width:300px;height:100px;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14px;border:1px solid red;" contenteditable>
    <div>
        first text
    </div>
    <div>
        second text
    </div>
    ...
    <div>
        other texts
    </div>
</div>
```